# How to add a scrollbar to a custom SurfaceView of a virtual height

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView which has a fixed height within the game (let's say it is always 400 pixels high). However, the content that I display within that SurfaceView is tile-based, so at any point within the game, the content can have a "virtual" height of any value, 400 or more pixels. When the content height is larger than the SurfaceView height, the user can scroll that content up and down. When that happens, I would like to add a standard scrollbar to indicate where the user is scrolling currently within that content.

How is it possible to add the standard scrollbar and change its length (height in this case) depending on the height of my "virtual" content? Thank you!